#  X509Certificate2: Internal error

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, x509certificate, x509certificate2

When I try to execute code below I got an error:

> Internal error occurred.

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2( p12FileBytes, p12FilePassword );
```

when I added

```
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet(
   new X509Certificate2(
      p12FileBytes, p12FilePassword,  X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)).
```

I got another error:

> Access Denied.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Stepan.

Answer (score 1):

Run the second code with elevated privileges.